# How to escape spaces while using command's output in command line

Tags: shell, command-line, find, quoting, command-substitution

I want to perform the following command in command line :

```
$ md5sum $(find . -type f)
```

But this would cause problems when it encounter files with spaces in filenames :

```
md5sum: Kaufmann: No such file or directory
md5sum: Mobile: No such file or directory
md5sum: 3D: No such file or directory
md5sum: Graphics: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this way instead:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
```

This way spaces in the matched filenames will be handled correctly.